# Any way help to revert part of a histroy commit in git?

Tags: git, git-revert

suppose i have below commits history in a git repository (all changes are made on one single file)

1. remove function `foo()` and `bar()`, modify function `baz()`
2. change something else

Now i want to re-add the function `foo()` back. What I desired is a interact manually way to do this. For example, an editor is opened in side-by-side diff mode. On one side is the version before the commit #1 (which include function `foo()`), on the other side is my local working copy. So that I can copy anything I want from the history side to working copy side.

Is there any `git` commands can help me to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution, which is what I'd probably do:

```bsh
# Stash any current modifications to be safe.
git stash

# Make a new commit that re-adds foo, bar and maz
git revert <sha of the commit with your function>

# Remove the commit you just created, but leave the file changes.
git reset HEAD^

# Interactively decide which chunks of code you actually want.
# Just follow the instructions, type '?' for help.
git add -p

# Commit all of the changes that you staged.
git commit

# Discard all the other stuff you didn't accept.
git checkout .
```